# find unix command and NTFS Stream

Tags: ntfs

Suppose I have a partition and some files have been hidden by NTFS Stream.
I have two serious question:

- Is it possible to find them via `find` unix command?
- How can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the unix `find` command doesn't know anything about ADS.
The [ntfs-3g](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14297/can-nix-handle-ntfs-ads-data-streams) driver at least knows about them. If they are indeed mapped to extended attributes on Linux, you should be able to list them with `lsattr`. Probably there are the more stricter kernel limits in place for the size of the attributes, so you might not be able to get all the data this way.

You are better off using Windows and something like [AlternateStreamView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html) or [Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams)